# Why the font change from 12pt to 17pt in my thesis?

Tags: fontsize

could you help me to solve the problem that change my font size from 12pt to 17pt in (2nd Copyright) which has been presented in my code, I don't know what is happen to change my font size after add (Examination Committee) page, 
my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\UseRawInputEncoding % to solve the problem of UTF-8 error in jabref.
\usepackage{times} %Times new roman font
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{setspace} % to change space between lines

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\huge\sc\centering}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setstretch{1.5}

\chapter*{Copyright}
Copyright 2018.All rights reserved, no part of this thesis may be reproduced in any form, electronic or mechanical, including photocopy, recording scanning, or any information, without the permission in writhing from the author or the Directorate of Graduate Studies and Training university.\\
\newpage

% Examination Committee
\Large\textbf{University \hfill Faculty of Engineering}
\vspace*{-6mm}
\begin{center}
\Large\textbf{Department of Electrical and Electronic Engineering}\\
\vspace*{6mm}
\setstretch{1.3}
\LARGE\textbf{Maximum power point tracking  }\\
\vspace*{4mm}
\Large{By}\\
\Large\textbf {Joun}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
\Large {This Thesis was Successfully Defended and Approved on \textbf{2018}}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
\Large{Supervisor}\\
\Large\textbf {Dr.  }\\
\Large{Signature:\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
\Large{Dr\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots \textbf{(Internal examiner)}}\\
\Large{Signature:\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots}\\
\Large{Dr\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\textbf{(External examiner)}}\\
\Large{Signature:\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots}\\
\vspace*{1mm}
\large\textbf {(Dean of Faculty)\hfill(Director of Graduate studies and training)}
\end{center}
\newpage

\setstretch{1.5}
\chapter*{2nd Copyright}
Copyright 2018.All rights reserved, no part of this thesis may be reproduced in any form, electronic or mechanical, including photocopy, recording scanning, or any information, without the permission in writhing from the author or the Directorate of Graduate Studies and Training university.\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the fontsize back to `\normalsize`. By the way, please note that size commands like `\Large` etc. are switches and don't take arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\UseRawInputEncoding % to solve the problem of UTF-8 error in jabref.
\usepackage{times} %Times new roman font
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{setspace} % to change space between lines

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\huge\sc\centering}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setstretch{1.5}

\chapter*{Copyright}
Copyright 2018.All rights reserved, no part of this thesis may be reproduced in any form, electronic or mechanical, including photocopy, recording scanning, or any information, without the permission in writhing from the author or the Directorate of Graduate Studies and Training university.\\
\newpage

% Examination Committee
\Large\textbf{University \hfill Faculty of Engineering}
\vspace*{-6mm}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Department of Electrical and Electronic Engineering}\\
\vspace*{6mm}
\setstretch{1.3}
\LARGE\textbf{Maximum power point tracking  }\\
\vspace*{4mm}
\Large By\\
\textbf {Joun}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
This Thesis was Successfully Defended and Approved on \textbf{2018}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
Supervisor\\
\textbf{Dr.} \\
Signature:\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
\vspace*{2mm}
Dr\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots \textbf{(Internal examiner)}\\
Signature:\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
Dr\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\textbf{(External examiner)}\\
Signature:\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
\vspace*{1mm}
\large\textbf {(Dean of Faculty)\hfill(Director of Graduate studies and training)}
\end{center}

\newpage

\setstretch{1.5}
\chapter*{2nd Copyright}
\normalsize Copyright 2018.All rights reserved, no part of this thesis may be reproduced in any form, electronic or mechanical, including photocopy, recording scanning, or any information, without the permission in writhing from the author or the Directorate of Graduate Studies and Training university.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understood what happen now, the end of the page 2 I used  `\large\textbf {(Dean of Faculty)` so all pages after page 2 the font size change to 17pt, then we can use `\normalsize` in the beginning of page 3 to set default font size (12pt) for all pages after page 2,  @Milo thanks very much for your helping.